# AngularJS routing multiple ui-views for the same URL?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I need multiple `ui-views` for one `URL` (my homepage). The limitation for `ui-routing` is that I can't have multiple `<div ui-view></div>` but they have to be in their nested states.

```
<div class="left-div">
  <div ui-view></div>
  <button ui-sref="1"></button>
  <button ui-sref="2"></button>
  <button ui-sref="3"></button>
</div>

<div class="right-div">
  <button ui-sref="3"></button>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

How do I make it so that `ui-sref=1` and `ui-sref=2` will update the `ui-view` inside:

```
<div class="left-div"></div>
```

and ui-sref=3 will update the ui-view inside `<div class="right-div"></div>`

The issue I encountered when I used ui-router was that upon changes from `ui-sref` from `1 -> 3` or `2 -> 3` the `ui-view` of `left-div` will disappear because the `URL` changes.

How do I approach this?

EDIT- My current state views

```js
chatApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home')

    $stateProvider

            .state('friend', {
                url: '/friend',
                templateUrl: 'friend.html'
            })

            .state('group', {
                url: '/group',
                templateUrl: 'group.html'
            })

            .state('search', {
                url: '/search',
                templateUrl: 'search.html'
            })

            .state('home', {
                url: '/search',
                templateUrl: 'search.html'
            })

            .state('public', {
                url: '/public',
                views: {
                    'publicView': { templateUrl: 'private-chat.html' }
                }
            });
```

```html
  <div class="col-md-3 left-col-friends" ng-controller="friendListCtrl">

    <div class="friends-list-navigation">
      <div class="option-wrapper">

        <div class="col-xs-3 home-option" ui-sref="public"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 friend-option" ui-sref="friend"><i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 group-option" ui-sref="group"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 search-option" ui-sref="search"><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i></div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="friends-list-display">
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9 middle-col-chat" ng-controller="publicCtrl">
    <div class="bubble-frame-public">
      <div ui-view="publicView"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="input-fields-wrapper" emoji-form emoji-message="emojiMessage">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <textarea class="col-md-4" id="messageInput" ng-model="emojiMessage.messagetext"></textarea>
      </div>



      <div class="col-md-3">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-send-public-msg" ng-click="emojiMessage.replyToUser()"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="emojibtn">
          <i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></button>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Please post your state configuration. Is the HTML above your root template?

Comment: No, I threw my code out as It couldn't serve the purpose I wanted.

Comment: Ypu should make the nested. View.  As named view

Comment: You can include the other views and ui-route only one view.

Comment: Thanks for posting all that. Which states are you having issues with?

Comment: I want to know if I can change the states under two separate ui-views but under one url? if that makes sense, that way when I change states of one ui-view while my other ui-view state remains the same

Comment: I think what you're saying is possible. But I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly your desired behavior is. Which states are changing? Which remains the same? What's the default desired behavior?

Comment: is there a chat on here? so I can explain it better to you?

Comment: I have a left div and a right div ( both on the same url i.e http://localhost:9000/fullscreen#/home ) . I want the left tab to have 3 seperate nested views. I want the right tab to have a view completely independent regardless of the states of the left div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a guess that the `publicView` is the view you're wanting to stay unchanged while the other views are changing. Here's one way to tackle it.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'search.html'
            },
            'publicView@': {
                templateUrl: 'private-chat.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home.friend', {
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'friend.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('home.group', {
        views: {
            '@': {
                templateUrl: 'group.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

The default URL is `/home`. When it's accessed, `publicView` is populated with `private-chat.html` and the unnamed `ui-view` is populated with `search.html`.

For the `friend` and `group` states, they **leave the `publicView` alone** and they **don't use new URLs**, which is what I think you're going for. This is accomplished by making them children states of `home` and by specificying absolutely which views should be altered.

Comment: so the '@' is the syntax to target an nameless ui-view?

Comment: Kind of. The portion before the `@` is the view's name, which in this case is unnamed as you said. The portion after the `@` is the state to target, which in this case is also unnamed, which targets the root template. So `'@'` targets the unnamed view in the root template. [More on this here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

Comment: Thanks, It works, is there anyway we can open a chat though? I encountered a small issue. Also approved your answer

Comment: for example I am on friend.html view and I go on /home I want friend.html to stay. Or if I am on group.html and I go on /home I want the group.html tab to stay.

Comment: oh no, I don't have enough reputation to chat.

Comment: Post it as a new question and we'll take a look.